# Anyway to make body scrollbar appear if absolute position element goes below screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way to do this? I don't want the content to go below the screen without it being scrollable. (This is for people who may have smaller screens than most)

Comment: Do you mean horizontally or vertically (or both)? Can you demonstrate the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/ / http://jsbin.com/

Comment: Vertical. Just make an absolutely positioned div that's height is more than the current screen height to see what I mean (I am away from my laptop at this moment or I would demonstrate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **NB:** Levi Putna is right in [pointing out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8910921/990877) that this behaviour only occurs if the `<div>` is empty.

Two options:

1. You could set a [`min-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/min-height) and [`min-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/min-width) the `<body>`.
2. You could set `height` on the `<body>` using JavaScript when the window is resized.

---

**Setting `min-height` and `min-width`**:

For example, if the absolutely positioned `<div>` is 400 × 300 pixels:

```css
body {
    min-height: 400px;
    min-width: 300px;
}
```

Limitations:

- Internet Explorer 6 **lacks support** for this, although there are easy hacks to fix that. At this point, `min-height` works in practically every other browser out there.
- There is no way to accomodate a dynamically sized `<div>`, expect by overcompensating.

---

**Dynamically setting `height` (when window is resized)**:

Given an absolutely positioned `<div>` of 400 × 300 pixels, positioned at [0,0]:

```js
var $win = $(window);

$win.resize(function(){
    var height = Math.max(400, $win.height());
    var width  = Math.max(300, $win.width());
    $('body').css({
        height: height,
        width:  width
    });
});
```

Or, if the `<div>`'s dimensions or position are variable:

```js
var $win = $(window);
var $div = $('#thediv'); // the absolutely positioned div

$win.resize(function(){
    var offset = $div.offset();
    var height = $div.outerHeight() + offset.top;
    var width  = $div.outerWidth() + offset.left;

    height = Math.max(height, $win.height());
    width  = Math.max(width, $win.width());  

    $('body').css({
        height: height,
        width:  width
    });
});
```

By using [`outerHeight`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) and [`outerWidth`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/), padding and border are included. By using [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) (instead of the CSS `top` and `left`, the position is taken relative to the document, not to the [offset parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetParent).

Comment: Okay thanks I'll try that when I get back to my laptop. (also I'm not worried about IE 6 or earlier, I'm choosing not to support earlier than that, as my site is using socket io a lot and that doesn't support further back than 6.

Comment: If you're happy to use JavaScript to fix this, you should just set the `body` height to the height of the absolutely positioned `div` when the window is resized.

Comment: How do you detect window resize?

Comment: Yes thank you, min-height works perfectly. Thanks for the other solutions as well, I'm not going to worry about IE6, I use min-width throughout my site.

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand this is what you are doing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="scroll-div" style="position:absolute; height:2000px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and expecting to get a scrollbar? From what I understand the browser won’t render the div or at least the scroll bar until you add some content.

If you simply add some content to the div (scroll-div) you will get the scroll bar.

Comment: +1, even though technically not an answer to OP's question. Thanks for making me realise I was blindly assuming this was caused by the the div's position... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(window).resize(function(){...});` if you are using jquery or simply `<body onresize="myResize()" >` for native javascript.